# Visual C++ 6 "LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file inputFile.obj" - multicore issue?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I have a solution with 11 projects. Project B is listed in the dependencies as dependent on project A. After a "Clean", folder ..\A\Debug\ is empty. When I do a batch build, A compiles successfully, then B starts compiling. Right after A compiles, I looked into the ..A\Debug folder and the obj files were not there yet. It seems they only appeared after B failed with that LNK1181 error message.

Some googling yielded this - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815645, which is clearly not the issue here, or that having more than one core can cause some randomness in which the projects are being built.

Is there any other cause, like those obj files being cached and not written to the disk in time? Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: For clarification, "Project B is listed in the dependencies as dependent on project A." You mean when you open the solution file's list of project dependencies and select Project B, the depends-on list has Project A checked, right?

Comment: VS6 never supported concurrent builds.  Pretty odd to have one project have a dependency on the .obj files created by another btw, this is normally done by having A generate a static library.  This is the kind of problem caused by anti-malware, disable it or make an exclusion.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, you are correct.

Comment: @HansPassant So... should I just disable the antivirus for the duration of the build? Most of the code wasn't written by me, when the structure of the solution was set up I was still playing with my Batman toys.